# Google mobile version of webpages (proxy)

Tags: google, website, mobile

I remember seeing some service offered by Google which lets you enter in a URL and it will output a mobile version of the page for you.

Does Google still provide such a service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for [this](http://www.google.com/gwt/n) service.
**Address:** http://www.google.com/gwt/n

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: site appears to be shutdown

Answer (score 0):

As of mid-2016, this service is still around, but now it redirects from `http://www.google.com/gwt/n?u=%s` to `http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=%s&f=1&s=1&source=wax`

For instance, http://googleweblight.com/?lite_url=https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/7540/google-mobile-version-of-webpages-proxy&f=1&s=1&source=wax

(If you remove the `&f=1&s=1&source=wax` you get a transcoded version, but not a mobile version.)

There is a little information here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6211428?hl=en